# PSQL not translating keyboard command after running query

Tags: bash, cygwin, psql, console2

Here is how I reproduce the issue:

1. Log onto psql and hit up arrow (shows last event from history as expected):

   `mydb=> select * from some_table;`
2. Run any select query.
3. Hit up arrow a second time (shows non-translated input from keyboard):

   `mydb=> ^[[A`

I'm using psql 10.11.  Anyone have this issue before, or know how to fix it?  Goal is for the up arrow to always show the last command from history.

Comment: Is it possible that `select * from some_table;` printed special characters which changed terminal ?

Comment: @Philippe only special characters are pluses, minuses, and pipes.

Comment: Just to be sure, can you try with the query `SELECT 1;` ?

Comment: @Philippe same issue even with SELECT 1;

Comment: are you using cygwin or windows psql ? Are you running psql from Mintty or CMD ?

Comment: @matzeri I'm using cygwin within a console2 terminal (and running psql within the console2 terminal).

Comment: Console2 is not a Cygwin package. Have you tried from Mintty ? Cygwin PSQL version is 12.x are you using a Windows 10.11 version ?  https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=psql.exe&arch=x86_64

Comment: This is my exact setup https://www.bryanlor.com/blog/cygwin-tutorial-integrating-cygwin-console2-windows.  PSQL version is 10.11.  And I have not tried Mintty.  If this doesn't work, sticking with pgadmin is not an issue.

Comment: Instead of Console2, can you start CMD window, run psql, just to see the same pb occurs ?